# How to access a variable in a method in a class from another method in the same class

Tags: python

**There are no errors or problems with the below code** I want to "connect" this script to an external file or database so that that "my_dict" dictionary can have its contents stored and used after the script is executed. **I am looking for ideas on how to make this happen.** I am not asking for the code to be fixed as it is functional. It is merely there to provide context.

```
my_dict = {}


class password(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def username_input(self):
        self.user = str(input("Please enter the username you would like to use: "))
        return self.user
        #gets the input for a username


    def password_input(self):
        self.passw = str(input("Please enter the password you would like to use: "))
        return self.passw
        #gets the input for a password


    def username_creator(self):
        password.username_input(self)
        return self.user


    def password_creator(self):
        password.password_input(self)
        return self.passw

    def swap_username(self, new_pass, old_pass):
        my_dict[new_pass] = my_dict.pop(old_pass)

    def swap_password(self, new_pas, old_pas):
        my_dict[old_pas] = new_pas



    def username_change(self):
        self.d = input("please enter your username: ")
        for key in my_dict:
            if key == self.d:
                self.x = input("enter a  new username: ")
                password().swap_username(self.x, self.d)
                print("your username has been updated!")
                break

            else:
                print("the username you entered does not exist in our records")
                password().username_change()


    def password_change(self):
        self.e = input("please enter your username: ")
        self.q = input("please enter your password: ")
        for key, value in my_dict.items():
            if key == self.e and value == self.q:
                self.z = input("enter a new password: ")
                password().swap_password(self.z, self.e)
                break
            else:
                print ('the combination  entered does not exist in our records')
                password().password_change()



    make_a_username = password()
    my_dict.update({(make_a_username.username_creator()): (make_a_username.password_creator())})
```

Comment: At an (admittedly cursory) glance, your code seems like a solid way to go about it. What problem are you having here?

Comment: I would like to know how to "connect" my_dict to an external file or database so that when I call username_creator() and the like to create or make changes to usernames, the results are stored even after the program finished executing.

Comment: Calling methods like this: `password.username_input(self)` is very unconventional. use `self.username_input()`. But anyway, your question and title are pretty broad. The answer is, "generally, you use attributes".  You could also pass values as arguments to functions and have functions return values. You've pasted a lot of code here, what exactly isn't working? Please edit your question to address a specific issue, and try to distill it down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving this is by storing `my_dict` in a file. So basically, whenever you start the app, you'd be loading `my_dict` from the file, and before closing, storing the updated `my_dict` in the file again. Since it's a dictionary, you could store it in JSON.

So, what you're ultimately doing is:

```
// to save
json_string = json.dumps(datastore)
// now write this string to a file

// to load, first read json_string from file. Then,
my_dict = json.loads(json_string)
```

Comment: would you mind letting me know where these commands should go in my script? Thanks!

Comment: json.loads(json_string) would go at the beginning, where you have initialized my_dict. If the file is empty, then my_dict is empty too.
Then, ideally, you would save to the file whenever you're updating my_dict in the code. Does this make sense? It isn't as straighforward as just writing the command in a single place to handle every case :)

Comment: If it answers your question, please accept the answer :) Thanks!